# Calculate trend values by regression in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, regression, trend

I have a matrix with dimensions of 19 rows and 7541502 columns.
I want to get the trend of each column using regression.
This is possible by using MATLAB function but requires a lot of time.
The written function is as follows:

```
Data = box1;
[r, c] = size(Data);
X = [1:r]'; Total = [];
for j = 1:c;
   Y = Data(:, j);
   [b1, bint1] = regress(Y, [ones(size(Y)) X]);
   Qs = [bint1(2, :), b1(2, :)];
   Total = [Total; Qs];
end
```

Is there a way to speed up Mfile in MATLAB?
Is there a way to calculate regression without using functions?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing `Total` to be the correct size before entering the for loop.

```
Total = zeros(c, 2);
```

instead of:

```
Total = [];
```

Comment: Thanks. I used this command "Total = nan(c , 3 );" But still the time of calculation is long

Comment: Prealocating should have sped it up at least a bit. My guess is that the remaining time is pretty close to what your computer is capable of. You're doing a fair amount of computation with all of those regressions.